# why php spl_autoload_register and ajax doesn't work together?

Tags: php, ajax, spl-autoload-register

This is my index.php file:

```
function Loader($class)
{
    $base=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

    if (file_exists($base.'/app/'.$class.'.php')) {
    include($base.'/app/'.$class.'.php');
    return true;
    }
  return false;
}

spl_autoload_register('Loader');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my main.js file i do AJAX call:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'controllers/UserController.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            model: model,
            method: method
        },

        success: function(result) {

            if (typeof(template) != 'undefined'){

                $.get('http://localhost/heliox/templates/'+template, function(data)     {

                    $(target).empty();

                    $(target).html(_.template(data,{data:result}));

                });
            } 
        }
    });
```

In UserController.php file i have:

```
Class UserController extends BaseController
{

    public function test()
    {
    echo "test";
    }
}

$UserController = new UserController;
```

When i place my "Loader" function inside UserController file it is working fine and class BaseController is loaded, but when the function is inside my index.php file and i do AJAX call i get :

> Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\heliox\controllers\UserController.php on line 13.

Comment: Because `UserControler.php` knows nothing about `index.php` and autoloader defined there.

Comment: so it is diffirent session is it ?

Comment: It's different starting point. In php you have to include files to access functions defined in them.

Comment: Ok i think i got it - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

With ajax call you are accessing `controllers/UserController.php` directly. In this file you have only class declaration thet extends other class. at this point PHP interpreter knows nothing about `index.php` and autoload function registered in it, so it will fail to parse the file, since it does know nothing about `BaseController` or where to search for it.

What you need is called bootstraping - put all code essential to run your application (like registering autoloaders, including libraries, loading config files etc.) into one file, that will be included by every file accessed directly.

Comment: Does the bootstrap file have to be located in the project's root directory to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/user/your_parameters',
```